# First whispered, then shouted

Tags: riddle, pattern, rebus

I'm working on a puzzle that seems to involve capital and lowercase letters. The arrangement of the letters seems to all be unique. There are no repeating phrases or sets. I wanted to know if my approach is correct, or if I should be rethinking everything.

Here is the initial passage

`Find adjacent four letter groups, first whispered, then shouted`

Here is a small snippet of the 'groups' in question.

```
srASBpeThwTwhdZVPOaECJhGnxhRKzxrbMSDyGZGNZBbCOKvPpJKKaQEcoLGBfIi
KtpVsROccWwgrWdEqtNFskeDnFbfKWVEeLvtBUlWrOMgtxsaSkctfJQfdOGRNMze
BlFsCFafWXzvrGfazhEruTMOETzZRYnuHsrtHeYivQdXFnwdDslSSGpfOMyrhbgk
OnPiwDTzUBbRaJzGbvUGmVzzTPRaXmLZsXyElKjzwXUYUqiuggHiSzHiGSuQhgHT
ICVWIjVXMUXOQhPdEskSprJHQvvtRtNQEVUwkGGqDUrAXzWTMyUYIisiOxlTHcIs
FfSnhzmCgEwmoWChrqkyNdtdLFWErzlEprlTNZsPfedCDEsqvmLWmxgCxpmSPTjG
SxtXINfaDztBUNdiQWoaIgFkqajwhInhMzczvmTJjwgtSGGoIbozCJgVurJetNXS
XWeduNjPVlpZtDimsizGqUjaLjYWvlRdYdrWvHzNUnKOlAUpTBMkUNFqYLvQKoQi
PPwvndXenRCVaBotNEKkJPUrYnaWAgizfeHyQMoFICbCqKELTmUYvqPYpzKVBYPT
LxRLMyexgApRCWDjhQAsDQhRGStiyGMEAWoBLFpsdbGGxFbgIarMglYofcZXILlF
lCvkCkCXybTKiYrHLpWXbngLJyVIzhwPIqSQlHURyrrtBTUbyrmMEquLvVjfKrRz
TzVoiknxpIICbQGfptEtwvpvUkeqOvtCOuArDtavZFszWBStWtqEGLIdKuVMTFRX
hOWPpjHcEWmthjrKXEnfeNKDmPEyvneMQrDBGZdibvyCCFlfMFPsXhhADOZwmmoJ
kqsyNaPoKLuPsaLzvkpkVbRiAfOxsECFcuLWpfNPkfgIbpAuEXEoHLtrWtLJmHEM
IxsvZVryZQxcUgnZgDSlXjSroSBAiwpkqgiCVksMaVuhZpIqhDQglSmjUqYYAzQS
```

The statement (I think) means that there will be four of these sets

`hOWPpjHcEWmthjrKXEnfeNKDmPEyvneMQrDBGZdibvyCCFlfMFPsXhhADOZwmmoJ`

and in this set, it needs to start off as lowercase, and then becomes uppercase.

The other idea that I had was that I need to be looking for groups of four letters that are lowercase, and uppercase, within close proximity to each other. I even went as far as color coding capital and lowercase groupings, but after a while, this didn't make much sense to me. I feel like I'm getting closer though.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Where is this from, and do you have permission to post it?

Comment: It comes from this website. https://challenge.hiringsolved.com/42
and It says nothing about permissions

Comment: FWIW this "challenge" was first posted in January 2014 (the winner to be first to complete it, no later than 2014-01-31) so I think it's fair to say it's no longer an ongoing contest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so i found your answer its:

> pqvsTNSQ

i wrote some code to parse through the whole text blob and find 4 lowercase followed by 4 uppercase. i tried the link and it worked so its probably correct.

goodluck on the other puzzles!

Comment: Jesus :P I was making it harder than was necessary 

Comment: well the next set looks more convoulted so goodluck with the challenge

Comment: Completed the last challenge, built a little crawler that followed each number... spoiler: it's not that interesting to follow the breadcrumbs :P

Answer (score 1):

Though kshishoo found it first, there's an even easier way of finding the answer:

> I used Inspect Element on the page and grabbed the code from it. Then I went to [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) and wrote a RegEx that matches 4 lowercase + 4 uppercase letters. The expression is as follows: `[a-z]{4}[A-Z]{4}`

And the result came out as follows:

> [image]